# Please provide ShowCaseView context

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use showcaseview package in flutter app. This is the code :

```
 final GlobalKey _topCounsellors = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _searchCounsellors = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _moreUsefulTips = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _needHelp = GlobalKey();

@override
void initState(){

    startShowCase();
}
startShowCase() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
        ShowCaseWidget.of(context).startShowCase(
            [_topCounsellors, _searchCounsellors, _moreUsefulTips, _needHelp]));
  }
```

In the build method there are 4 widgets that I want to showcase : one of them being this :

```
Showcase(
                                  blurValue: 1,
                                  description:
                                      "Here is more helpful information",
                                  key: _moreUsefulTips,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 140,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        var e = snapshot.data[1][index];
                                        return InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            //code 
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                                child: Image.network(
                                                  e.image,
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      itemCount: snapshot.data[1].length,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

I get an exception everytime I come on the page :

```
Another exception was thrown: Exception: Please provide ShowCaseView context
```

I am not including showcasewidget in material app rather did it in the previous widget from whence it came :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ShowCaseWidget(
            blurValue: 1,
            onFinish: () {
              logger.i('Completed');
            },
            builder: Builder(
              builder: (context) => SubDomainScreen(
                titleName: widget.title,
                owner: seeker,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```